# Bootstrap logo over fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to push the navbar line (and obviously the content as well) down according to logo height. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top custom-header" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header transparent">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logoSmall.png" alt="Page Logo"> Brand Title</a>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 custom-navbar-line">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills custom-nav-pills">
                        <li class="active"><a ng-href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-href="#">Page1</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-href="#">Page2</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-href="#">Page3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want:

[image: What I want]

What I get:

[image: What I get]

Note: Custom css classes have not much to do with the positioning.

Comment: post you css code please.

Comment: Why down vote? What I've tried is obvious in the question. If you read the bottom, custom classes are only for coloring, border-radius etc. Do you want me to put Bootstrap css in here?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="Page Logo"> Brand Title</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a.navbar-brand { /*or add another class instead of changing this*/
    display:block;
    margin:50px 0 10px 0; /* Adjust the margin : top right bottom left */
}
```

Just keep some margins on `top` and `bottom` of that `<a>` tag. Don't depend on other elements for margin of that `<a>` tag, instead apply `css`rule on itself for it's margin.

Or just put in inside another `.row`:

```
<div class='row'>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logoSmall.png" alt="Page Logo"> Brand Title</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close your the `<div class="container">` and open a new `container` with a margin top around the second row of the nav bar.

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/id5Bcmuth7)

Updated HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top custom-header" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header transparent">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="Page Logo"> Brand Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container new-nav-line">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 custom-navbar-line">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills custom-nav-pills">
                        <li class="active"><a ng-href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-href="#">Page1</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-href="#">Page2</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-href="#">Page3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.new-nav-line{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: But this solution doesn't push the content below header.

Comment: So you may have to add a margin-top to your content.  I don't see content html in your question so I didn't work with that.

Comment: And when I resize the page, margin-top doesn't goes away. I don't want to use @media for that if i don't have to.

Comment: not sure what you mean, the margin looks fine to me on bootply.  I can only work with the code you've provided.  I'm not here to write your website for you.

Comment: I don't want you to write my website for me. If you resize your bootply window (make it narrow), you'll get what i mean.

Comment: I did, it looks fine to me.  I launch the mobile browser window and resize that or else I get a message about bootply not working in smaller screen resolutions.  We don't need to go back and forth here.  However I recommend that you say "Thank you" and try to figure out a solution for yourself if the ones here aren't working for you.

Comment: Of course, thanks for trying to help, don't get me wrong. But simply it doesn't work, should I lie to you?. You don't have to be so defensive and say things like i'm not here to write your website, we are not working for you etc. I don't see stackoverflow in that way, don't worry. Btw, I think the code I provided is quite enough to solve the problem. But then again, thanks for trying though.